# cd 'brew --prefix': no such file or directory

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

```
> cd 'brew --prefix'
-bash: cd: brew --prefix: No such file or directory
```

Additional errors:

```
> brew update
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

> brew doctor
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/reporting-bugs
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:840:in `check_for_outdated_homebrew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:310:in `cd'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:310:in `chdir'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:310:in `cd'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:837:in `check_for_outdated_homebrew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:907:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:907:in `doctor'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:906:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:906:in `doctor'
/usr/local/bin/brew:83:in `send'
/usr/local/bin/brew:83
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do your cd command, you need to use backticks, not the quotation mark (putting this in an answer because difficult to format)

```
cd `brew --prefix`
```

The backticks make the shell execute the command and return the value. (in this case `brew --prefix` transforms into the directory where `homebrew` is installed).  For example, in a very simple case:

```
cd `echo '..'`
```

Transforms into:

```
cd ..
```

Which goes up a directory.

It looks like something is wrong with the git repo for your homebrew install. If you haven't installed a  lot, might be easier to just uninstall and reinstall and try again. You should go to the docs for brew, but you can just `rm -rf` on your Cellar folder and have everything return to its original state.  [More info here](https://gist.github.com/1173223).

Comment: And that's why we should all use `$()` instead.